How can a cryptographic primitive make a SNARK a zk-SNARK?
I'm currently reading this book by Justin Thaler that describes the process of constructing a zk-SNARK:

"Argument systems are typically developed in a two-step process.
First, an information-theoretically secure protocol, such as an IP,
multi-prover interactive proof (MIP), or probabilistically checkable
proof (PCP), is developed for a model involving one or more provers
that are assumed to behave in some restricted manner (e.g., in an MIP,
the provers are assumed not to send information to each other about
the challenges they receive from the verifier). Second, the
information-theoretically secure protocol is combined with
cryptography to “force” a (single) prover to behave in the restricted
manner, thereby yielding an argument system. This second step also
often endows the resulting argument system with important properties,
such as zero-knowledge, succinctness, and non-interactivity. If the
resulting argument satisfies all of these properties, then it is in
fact a zk-SNARK."

I don't see how a cryptographic primitive can make a SNARK a zk-SNARK, like he describes it here. My understanding is that Zero Knowledge doesn't rely on complexity assumptions, so I thought the zero-knowledge property must come from the information-theoretically secure protocol, not the choice of cryptographic primitive. Which properties of a zk-SNARK come from cryptography and which come from the information-theoretically secure protocol?

You usually need a cryptographic assumption for zero-knowledge proof systems. But you can have the computational assumption on either the prover or verifier (e.g. using commitments it depends if the binding or hiding criteria is computational). Since the "AR" in "SNARK" stands for argument, i.e. computational soundness, in theory nothing prevents you from having statistical ZK. But there might be constructions of "zk-SNARK" where the computational assumption holds both ways, I can't say.
